# Can't make webdriver to wait for page to load

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

First of all, I am familiar and read multiple times how to use implicit and explicit waits in Selenium. I have tried:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait() 
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout()
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout()
```

but none of them make the browser to wait. Explicit waits work, but it can't be that I need to add an explicit wait every single time I interact with an element (clicking, searching, etc.). As you can imagine, I'm trying to avoid using Thread.sleep().

I'm using Chromedriver as driver listener.

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

I also tried the JavascriptExecutor but doesn't work either. Maybe my implementation is wrong, or maybe it is because it's the same page. For example, I'm performing a search inside a website. The same page reloads after the search but the driver doesn't wait for it to load the results.

This is the executor's code, added in a page named JobsPage:
    public void checkPageIsReady() {

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = driver;

    if (js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete")){
        System.out.println("Page Is loaded.");
        return;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<25; i++){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        //To check page ready state.
        if (js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete")){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling it after the steps that aren't loading in another class named JobsTest:

```
    JobsPage jobsPage = new JobsPage(driver);
    jobsPage.checkPageIsReady();
    jobsPage.searchById("44684");
```

Comment: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits -- here is what you need.

Comment: If that doesn't help, you'll have to be more explicit about the scenario you are trying to resolve.

Comment: Please have a read through [ask], especially how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi Ratmir, I have already read Selenium's guide. As I mentioned, explicit waits work, but I have to add an explicit wait on EACH step of my test, every time I interact with an element and from my perspective this doesn't seem to be efficient. I am looking for a way to apply the "wait for page to load" for all my steps.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with two ways :

**Fist one**
 Set implicit wait after creating the web driver instance: driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait()

```
After navigate to that page call following method:
new WebDriverWait(driver, MyDefaultTimeout).Until(
    d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor) d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));

**Second one:**

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
By itemonnextpage= By.xpath("//div[.='itemonnextpage']");

// get the "itemonnextpage" element
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(itemonnextpage));
```

Comment: Hi Shiv, as I mentioned, explicit waits work (your second way), but I have to add an explicit wait on EACH step of my test, every time I interact with an element and from my perspective this doesn't seem to be efficient. 
I also tried the javascript executor but doesn't work. Maybe my implementation is wrong, or maybe it is because it's the same page. For example, I'm performing a search inside a website. The page reloads after the search but the driver doesn't wait for it to load.